# Empty file json as output in Scrapy

Tags: python, json, regex, scrapy, rule

I state that I've already read some answers about the same problem but the I couldn't solve my issue.
I'm new in Python, I'm trying to extract data from Aptoide about apps and stores, and I want an output result as .json file (or csv), but the file I get is empty, I don't know the reason.

This is my code:

```
    import scrapy

    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

    class ApptoideItem(scrapy.Item):
        app_name = scrapy.Field()
        rating = scrapy.Field()
        security_status = scrapy.Field()
        good_flag = scrapy.Field()
        licence_flag = scrapy.Field()
        fake_flag = scrapy.Field()
        freeze_flag = scrapy.Field()
        virus_flag = scrapy.Field()
        five_stars = scrapy.Field()
        four_stars = scrapy.Field()
        three_stars = scrapy.Field()
        two_stars = scrapy.Field()
        one_stars = scrapy.Field()
        info = scrapy.Field()
        download = scrapy.Field()
        version = scrapy.Field()
        size = scrapy.Field()
        link = scrapy.Field()
        store = scrapy.Field()

class AppSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "second"
    allowed_domains = ["aptoide.com"]
    start_urls = [ "http://www.aptoide.com/page/morestores/type:top" ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'\w+\.store\.aptoide\.com$'))),

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'\w+\.store\.aptoide\.com/app/market')), callback='parse_item')
        )


def parse_item(self, response):

    item = ApptoideItem()
    item['app_name']= str(response.css(".app_name::text").extract()[0])
    item['rating']= str(response.css(".app_rating_number::text").extract()[0])
    item['security_status']= str(response.css("#show_app_malware_data::text").extract()[0])
    item['good_flag']= int(response.css(".good > div:nth-child(3)::text").extract()[0])
    item['licence_flag']= int(response.css(".license > div:nth-child(3)::text").extract()[0])
    item['fake_flag']= int(response.css(".fake > div:nth-child(3)::text").extract()[0])
    item['freeze_flag']= int(response.css(".freeze > div:nth-child(3)::text").extract()[0])
    item['virus_flag']= int(response.css(".virus > div:nth-child(3)::text").extract()[0])
    item['five_stars']= int(response.css("div.app_ratting_bar_holder:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)::text").extract()[0])
    item['four_stars']= int(response.css("div.app_ratting_bar_holder:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3)::text").extract()[0])
    item['three_stars']= int(response.css("div.app_ratting_bar_holder:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(3)::text").extract()[0])
    item['two_stars']= int(response.css("div.app_ratting_bar_holder:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(3)::text").extract()[0])
    item['link']= response.url
    item['one_stars']= int(response.css("div.app_ratting_bar_holder:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(3)::text").extract()[0])
    item['download']= int(response.css("p.app_meta::text").re('(\d[\w\.]*)')[0].replace('.', ''))
    item['version']= str(response.css("p.app_meta::text").re('(\d[\w\.]*)')[1])
    item['size']= str(response.css("p.app_meta::text").re('(\d[\w\.]*)')[2])
    item['store_name']= str(response.css(".sec_header_txt::text").extract()[0])
    item['info_store']= str(response.css(".ter_header2::text").extract()[0])
    yield item
```

I'm pretty sure that the problema is that parse_item method never invoked, and I don't know the reason. The first rule follows the stores, while the second one follows apps in stores. I think the syntax of regular expressions is right.

Setting are:

```
CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 1000
CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT = 500
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
CONCURRENT_ITEMS = 1

BOT_NAME = 'nuovo'


SPIDER_MODULES = ['nuovo.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'nuovo.spiders'
```

Could anyone find the problem and suggest me a solution?

Comment: Have you checked that your xpath expressions work via `scrapy shell` ? Does the output perhaps come via `JavaScript` ? Additionally, `scrapy` provides a method called `extract_first()`, so you do not need to fiddle with the indices.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of errors, when you run the spider you can save the log and go through it with grep:

```
scrapy crawl spidername 2>&1 | tee crawl.log
```

Few errors that I found:

- your `ApptoideItem` is missing fields like `store_name` and few others.
- your whole `int()` conversion is insecure, meaning if your `response.css` returns None, which it does if it finds nothing, you get an error.

To resolve the second point I suggest looking into [scrapy ItemLoaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) which will allow you to specify default behaviour for some fields, like turn items in fields `_flag` to boolean etc.
Also as @Jan mentioned in the comments, you should use `extract_first()` method instead of `extract()[0]`, extract_first allows you to specify default attribute for when nothing is found, i.e. `.extract_first(default=0)`